# Ionic 3 select list from data

Tags: ionic-framework, select, ionic3

I am trying to load data from a http call into a select as per the code below.

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="dealer">
<ion-option *ngFor="let dealerDetails of dealers">{{dealerDetails.name}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

This returns

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
'ion-option' is not a known element:
1. If 'ion-option' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of 
this module.
2. If 'ion-option' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to 
the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
```

I have tried the # instead of the let to no avail.

also this code works perfectly for the list as per below code:

```
  <ion-list>
<ion-item *ngFor="let dealerDetails of dealers">{{dealerDetails.name}}</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you create a StackBlitz demonstrating your problem? I'm having trouble reproducing it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-khhhgj

Comment: That is the weird thing I have made apps like this before. I even took your example and added it to mine and it still broke.

Comment: I think it the issue is that I am on ionic 4
 ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.3.1 (node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-beta.15
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.8.7
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 0.8.7
   @angular/cli                  : 6.2.7
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.1.0

Comment: Works perfectly in Ionic 3 reverted to that for now

Comment: Good to hear :) Ionic 4 is still in beta, so staying with version 3 for a while might be the best choice...